# Invalid key error when updating a value of custom field with Ruby rally_api

Tags: ruby, rally

When I try to update a custom field like this:

```
@rally.update('defect', 1234567890, {'c_CustomField'=>newValue})
```

I get :

```
Error on request - https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/defect/1234567890.js - {:errors=>["Not authorized to perform action: Invalid key"]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you receive is specific to v2.0 of WS API . See Authorization section in [WS API documentation](https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/doc/webservice/). In v2.0 a security token is required to authorize Create and Update requests.

For example, if you update or create an artifact using an update or create URL, a security token must be obtained first:

GET a security token using this endpoint:

```
`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/security/authorize`
```

response:

```
{"OperationResult": {"_rallyAPIMajor": "2", "_rallyAPIMinor": "0", "Errors": [], "Warnings": [], "SecurityToken": "6a4b8....."}}
```

POST

```
`https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/HierarchicalRequirement/create?key=6a4b8...`.
```

However, rally_api gem 0.9.20 makes it transparent, and there is no need to request a token explicitly.

Here is an example where a custom field is updated:

```
require 'rally_api'

#Setup custom app information
headers = RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()
headers.name = "edit custom field"
headers.vendor = "Nick M RallyLab"
headers.version = "1.0"

# Connection to Rally
config = {:base_url => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm"}
config[:username] = "user"
config[:password] = "secret"
config[:workspace] = "W"
config[:project] = "P"
config[:version] = "v2.0"
config[:headers] = headers #from RallyAPI::CustomHttpHeader.new()

@rally = RallyAPI::RallyRestJson.new(config)

query = RallyAPI::RallyQuery.new()
query.type = :defect
query.fetch = "Name,FormattedID,CreationDate,Owner,UserName,c_MyCustomField"
query.workspace = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/workspace/1111.js" } 
query.project = {"_ref" => "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/project/2222.js" }
query.page_size = 200 #optional - default is 200
query.limit = 1000 #optional - default is 99999
query.project_scope_up = false
query.project_scope_down = true
query.order = "Name Asc"
query.query_string = "(FormattedID = DE13)"

results = @rally.find(query)

results.each do |d|
    puts "MyCustomField: #{d["c_MyCustomField"]}"
    d.read
    field_updates = {"c_MyCustomField" => "new text goes here"}
    d.update(field_updates)
    puts "MyCustomField: #{d["c_MyCustomField"]}"
end
```